# Why make user login in android SDK of PayuMoney gateway?

Tags: android, sdk, payumoney

I am trying to integrate PayUMoney SDK for android and successfully added the SDK in my application. When the user clicks on the pay button a login page opens up.

Why should the user be made to login/create an account for payu?

As soon as the user presses the pay button the options for payment should open up but that is not the case. I have tried the sample app given by them in [github](https://github.com/payu-intrepos/PayUMoney-Android-SDK)  too and seems that it has the same flow.

I got a video in [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qQ_DuebXYVE) showing the problem for anybody who would like to see what I am talking about.

Is this is the default work flow for PayUMoney or is there a way we can ignore the login and choose the payment option?

Most of the videos and tutorials show the old SDK integration method of PayU. If anybody could guide me with this it would be of much help.

Comment: yes, even payUmoney developer team didn't answer my query about this.

Comment: @jagapathi so did you get a solution to this problem?

Comment: nope there is no solution up to now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone who is looking for an answer in future. PayUMoney has changed their SDK for android. The sample application given by them during your SDK download from GitHub works totally fine and there is no way you can bypass the login screen they provide. You will not need to change anything in the sample app they provide. Just run the code:

1. Click on the pay button.
2. Enter any email id.
3. Select Guest Login below.
4. Click the login button.
   [image]

This should show you the payment option page and then after that use your testing credentials and everything should work like a charm.

I hope this helps.