# PayUmoney Login/SignUp Mandatory for Android SDK

Tags: android

I don't want the payU money Login/SignUp screen during the payment checkout in android application. How to by pass the signup or login Screen? Directly allow the customer to pay their payment with credit/debit card/net banking. And in production guest login option also not visible. Is there any solution?

Comment: You should ask that to PayU support.

Answer (score 0):

I had faced the same problem some weeks back and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45183801/2610503) is my answer to it. Hope it helps. This is the answer given by the tech team of PayUMoney.

Comment: Thank you for your response. But the problem is that for test guest login option is working. but when i make it for production guest option becomes invisible. Is the any solution for that. Thanks in advance

Comment: First of all have a full flow of your test credentials working, i.e. till the payment is successful. If that starts working fine then put in your login credentials and try. If the guest login doesn't show up for production still, try requesting for a callback in their web contact page. Or mail them at  merchantcare@payumoney.com stating that you want a guest login in your merchant id. PayUMoney has a very slow/bad service for customers so you will have to push them. That's what i did :)! All the best